# C: open second custom sized terminal and use it for output

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I am writing a program in C that is started simply by the terminal. Now I want to make the program itself open another terminal with a custom size and write its output in there.

I found the command

```
system("gnome-terminal");
```

which opens another terminal, but I can't find a function that lets me write into this second terminal. I am using Ubuntu.

If you have any idea, that would be great

Comment: You'd need to think in terms of `popen()` so that you can communicate with the program.  The `system()` function runs the Gnome terminal, but doesn't return until the terminal exits (so your program can't interact with the terminal — even if it had a way of doing so), unless the Gnome terminal always forks and the parent exits immediately.  Using `popen()` may still not be the solution; you may have to do more work (pseudo-tty, perhaps) so that you can write to the terminal from your program.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would probably be to write the output to a file, say /tmp/tmp96888 (tip: `mkstemp`) and then do something like

```
system("gnome-terminal --geometry=40x14 --command 'less /tmp/tmp96888'");
```

Or, to update continuously from the file:

```
system("gnome-terminal --geometry=40x14 --command 'tail -f /tmp/tmp96888'");
```

But if you can, I think the best way is to open a new terminal and run the program itself in it, and just print the output. It's only if you actually need to do things in the original window that you have to bother with a separate output window.

Comment: I will update the output during the run of the program, so I can't use a static file

Comment: thanks for your advice, I use the terminal the program is started in already for the main output. The second terminal is for additional information :)